# How to change what images are loaded into a ViewPager based on List Item clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have multiple images in the drawable folder but I want only certain ones loaded based on the item clicked in a previous ListView activity. So i am trying to learn how to lazy load the images instead of hard coding them into my xml file. I am a newbie and trying to teach myself android coming from a ios development background. Thanks in advance for any help.
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    public int getCount(){
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        int resId = 0;
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.amersenna);
            resId = R.layout.left;
            break;
        case 1:
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.amersenna);
            resId = R.layout.middle;
            break;
        case 2:
            iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.amersenna);
            resId = R.layout.right;
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View agr0, int agr1, Object agr2) {
        ((ViewPager) agr0).removeView((View)agr2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View agr0, Object agr1){
        return agr0 == ((View)agr1);
    }

    @Override 
    public Parcelable saveState(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTag(Object)` and `getTag()` methods from `View` class. Add an ArrayList object to each of your ImageViews. So when a particular ImageView is clicked you can fetch the attached ArrayList object using 'getTag()'. In this way you will be able to load different images when a particular list item is clicked, according to your need.